# Content pass over a fixed header

Tags: css, html

In my html page, i fixed my header with :

```
position : fixed
```

When i scroll down, then content of my page pass over the header. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming your HTML is the following:

```
<div id="header">...</div>
<div id="content">...</div>
```

Try the following CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #header {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
  }
  #content {
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
  }
 </style>
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want the header to be 2 and the content to be 1? That's what worked for me.

Comment: The larger the z-index, the higher it is. content should be 1 and header should be 2.

Comment: It's not necessary to change `z-index` of the content. Increasing it for the header is sufficient.