# Content behind header after scrolling back from anchor

Tags: header, anchor

**Update**: I have found out that this is a very specific problem with `<div>`'s with the combination of `overflow: hidden` and anchors. There seems to be no solid way around it. I now deleted the `overflow: hidden`. This solves my anchor problem, but creates extra space below my columns. This is not such a big problem, but if anyone knows how to get rid of the overflow without using `overflow: hidden`, suggestions would be really welcome. **End update**

I have a fairly simple website with a header in a `<div>` over two columns. The header and the columns are in one container. The header is NOT fixed; when scrolling down, the header goes out of view.

Now, my problem is with the anchors I want to add in the right column. The anchor itself works properly; when I click on the link on the top of my page, it jumps to `<h2>` just fine. It puts the title in the top of the screen just like I want it to. The problem is, however, that when I scroll back to the top, the upper part of my content in the columns has shifted behind the header. At first I thought it shifted all the way up to the top of the page, but now I see that that is not the case. I don't understand what the amount of pixels corresponds to. The columns themselves seem to keep the proper length; there is now extra empty space below the text.

I have read several questions of others on this website, but they all dealt with fixed headers, and their problem was that the anchor tag *itself* disappeared behind the header. I have tried the solutions proposed to this problem, but that causes my anchor tag to appear too low on the page and doesn't solve the problem that the upper part of my columns ends up behind the header.

Does anyone know how to fix this...?

My HTML for the page-setup:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <div id="columns">
        <div id="leftcolumn">
        </div>

        <div id="rightcolumn">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS for the header and the columns:

```
#header {
    width: 738px ;
    height: 298px ;
    padding: 0px ;
    position: relative; 
    }

#container {
    width: 738px ;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    margin-top: 0px ;
    margin-bottom: 0px ;
    padding: 0px ;
    }

#columns {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px ;    
    width: 738px ;
    background: #b43232 url(fauxcolumns.jpg) ;
    overflow: hidden ;  
    }   

#leftcolumn {
    float: left;
    width: 254px ;
    margin-top: 0px ;
    padding: 0px ;
    }

#rightcolumn {
    margin-left: 254px ;
    margin-top: 0px ;
    padding: 0px ;
    }
```

And, finally, my HTML for the anchor:

```
<a href="#text">Text</a>
<p>Text in between the top and the anchor.</p>
<a name="text"><h2>Text</h2></a>
<p>This is the text the anchor wants to take you to.</p>
```

So, to summarize: the anchor works, but when I scroll back to the top, the upper part of my content has now shifted behind the header. So I guess I want the *content* of my columns to align with the top of the column, instead of in some random place behind the header, but I can't imagine how to do it. Setting `top` or `margin-top` to either `#columns` or both columns separately doesn't work. I can't think of anything else...

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate 

See:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058498/content-pass-over-a-fixed-header